# valueOf() method in enum is not Working in java 7

Tags: java

I am using java 6 and my application is huge and its developed in java 6.
Now we trying to upgrade java version as 7.

But when i tried it to java 7 it will give compilation error in enum class.
In enum class i have defined valueOf() method so in java 7 it gives compilation error .

**Code**

```
public enum TestEnum {
 TESTONE,TESTTWO, NONE;

public String toString() {
    switch(this) {
        case TESTONE: 
            return "Test one";
        case TESTTWO: 
            return "Test two";
        case NONE: 
            return "None";
    }
    return null;
};

public static TestEnum valueOf(Class<TestEnum> enumType, String value){

        if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(TESTONE.toString()))
            return TestEnum.TESTONE;
        else if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(TESTTWO.toString()))
            return TestEnum.TESTTWO;
        else if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(NONE.toString()))
            return TestEnum.NONE;
        else
            return null;
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
Name clash: The method valueOf(Class<TestEnum>, String) of type TestEnum has the 
same erasure as valueOf(Class<T>, String) of type Enum<E> but does not hide it  TestEnum.java
```

**Update(Resolved)**

I changes valueOf() method and my file is compile.

```
public static TestEnum valueOf(TestEnum enumType, String value){

        if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(TESTONE.toString()))
            return TestEnum.TESTONE;
        else if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(TESTTWO.toString()))
            return TestEnum.TESTTWO;
        else if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(NONE.toString()))
            return TestEnum.NONE;
        else
            return null;
  }
```

Comment: For one thing, the `Class<TestEnum>` parameter is unused; for another, it's redundant, as the only class of that type is `TestEnum.class`.

Comment: This code gets `error: name clash: valueOf(Class<TestEnum>,String) in TestEnum and <T>valueOf(Class<T>,String) in Enum have the same erasure, yet neither hides the other` when compiled with `-source 1.6`.

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks i removed Class<> and its working

Comment: @SejalRudani well, is it working, really? You've now changed the semantics of your code, since the compiler will choose a different method in the rest of your code where you are invoking `valueOf`: it will pick the `Enum.valueOf(Class, String)` method, rather than the `TestEnum.valueOf(Class, String)` method.

Comment: @AndyTurner let me check further

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why it was working in Java 6, as [a method with that signature previously existed in Java 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class, java.lang.String)) (and has since Java 5).

However, for the sake of your developers' sanity, I would strongly recommend that you rename the method anyway: `Enum.valueOf` does something well-known, and you are attempting to provide a method which does something different. This would violate the principle of least surprise, and likely lead to unintentional results.

A name like `TestEnum.forName(String)` is a possible alternative.

---

Additionally: a `switch` in an enum over a variable of the type of that enum is a bit of a code smell. You can express the enum more nicely:

```
enum TestEnum {
  TESTONE("Test one"),TESTTWO("Test two"), NONE("None");

  private String str;

  private TestEnum(String str) {
    this.str = str;
  }

  @Override public String toString() {
    return str;
  }
}
```

which has the additional advantage of you not being able to accidentally omit the "string" form of any further enum values you add.

Similarly, you can do better than explicitly testing the string values:

```
enum TestEnum {
  /* values */;

  private static HashMap<String, TestEnum> forNameMapping;
  {
    forNameMapping = new HashMap<>();
    for (TestEnum t : TestEnum.values()) {
      forNameMapping.put(t.str.toLowerCase(), t);
    }
  }

  public static TestEnum forName(String str) {
    return forNameMapping.get(str.toLowerCase());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every enum is a subclass of `Enum<T>`. `Enum<T>` already defines a static method with the erasure `valueOf(Class,String)`. Since static methods cannot be overridden, you cannot define a static method with the same signature. You will have to call your method differently.